# Creating a verified badge for users with php

Tags: php, verification, badge

[please excuse the noob here - likely to embarass myself]

Trying to follow an existing script - essentially to replicate a verified badge commonly seen on social media platforms eg Twitter

Script is in php in a classes.php file in folder /includes/classes.php
Database table = 'user'for which i intend to create a column 'verified'after 'description'.
Values are
0 = not verified
1 = verified

[image: phpAdmin view of user table]

I have (fudged) got this so far, but am sure i have made some v basic errors

```
function getVERIFIED($id = null, $type = null) {

    $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `verified` = '%s' ORDER BY `idu` DESC LIMIT 0, 1", ($idu) ? $idu : $this->db->real_escape_string($this->idu)));
        $result = $query->fetch_assoc();

        if($result['verified'] == 1 {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This in turn will feed into an HTML script so that based on the returned value it will display the image/verified badge

```
<a href="'.(($this->getVerified($profile['idu'])) ? '<img src="'.$this->url.'/'.'/images/verified.png".'</a>
```

I do hope that made sense. Any pointers much appreciated

Comment: Change this from `if($result['verified'] == 1 {` to `if($result['verified'] == 1) {`. This is a syntax error I think.

Comment: you are missing a parenthesis in the if statement.

Comment: Thanks guys

Does it therefore follow that the rest of the logic/script is sound?

Will look to try it out later on. Thanks